# How do raises work for extended contracts?

Tags: contracts, raise, contract-extension

Background :

I am working as a contractual, and the recruitment firm assigned me this job and I accepted.

My contract ends soon, and the recruitment firm informed me that I was offered a contract extension.

I am currently being paid $35/hr and am hoping with the extention to get $40-45/hr.

How should I approach my firm about getting the raise?  Are there any normal expectations on this, or is it a purely case by case basis?

Comment: If you are asking, "What's the usual raise for extended contracts?", then your question is off-topic: 1. we are not a research service; 2. we don't do questions on salary numbers and percentages because this data is not only gro-specific and company-specific, it is highly perishable. We want readers to find our answers as relevant 5 years from now as they are relevant today.

Comment: I'm not really asking what an appropriate raise amount is. Most of the online resources, including the ones in the workplace SE talk about raises in a full-time position. Raises for contractual jobs in a recruitment firm (or contracting in general) is not so much discussed as full time raises. 

I was hoping to get insights on how this works, especially as you technically work for the recruitment agency, and your work/office boss is not the one you talk about raises with, unlike full time jobs. 

I hope this clears out things. :D

Comment: If you are asking who you should talk to about raises, then you should talk about money to the same people who pay you i.e. the recruiting agency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My contract ends soon, and the recruitment firm informed me that I was
>   offered a contract extension.
>
> Am I capable of asking for a raise? Specifically, what is the norm for
>   raises in the case of extended contracts?

Yes, you can ask for a raise.

Contract extensions are fundamentally the same as a new contract containing all the previous terms, but with new dates. You are free to accept or reject such a contract.

In my experience, it's far more common to just continue the current rate. When I hire contractors, I often extend their dates and don't expect to pay more. (And what I pay isn't the same as the compensation the individual receives, of course.) But that doesn't mean you must follow the norm.

Presumably, you were offered an extension, but haven't yet accepted the offer.

In your case, you can say "Yes, I'd like to extend my contract, but I want to change the terms. I'd like to get $X." If the firm accepts, then a new contract is drawn up with the new terms and dates.

Note that your counter-offer could be refused, in which case you would have to decide to stay at your current rate, or leave.